# Take average of specific cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel document which looks like this:

```
 Title | Value | Average |
     a |  023  |         |
       |  437  |         |
     b |  276  |         |
       |  057  |         |
       |  490  |         |
       |  389  |         |
     c |  497  |         |
       |  354  |         |
       |  939  |         |
```

I want to take the average of all the `a` values, which are `023`, `437`, etc. I'd like to do the same for all the `b` values and so on.

The problem is that these have different ranges; for `a` there are only two values, but for `b` there are four values.

I tried the following in the `Average` column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",AVERAGE(B2:B4))
```

So it shows an average if the cell next to it is not blank. I can now drag this formula down. The only problem is that it only checks the cell on its left and the one below that for the average, not until the `Title` column has another entry. I don't know how to implement that with my current Excel knowledge. Can someone suggest me which function to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy method is to add a helper column in Column D with the following formula In D2:

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,D1)
```

And copy down.

Then in C2 you would reference that in an AverageIF():

```
=AVERAGEIF(D:D,D2,B:B)
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of using a helper column, but wasn't sure how to implement it. This is smart!